# Spring UTF-8 replace chars "ě", "č", "ř" to "?"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I have problems with UTF-8 encoding.

I have a Spring-Boot REST Server. When I perform a PUT request to save an article and there are special characters in the content (like "ě", "č" or "ř") they will be replace by "?" characters. But if I edit an article using phpmyadmin and perform a GET request it returns "ě", "č" and "ř" correctly.

```
package cz.flay.fellcms.http;

import cz.flay.fellcms.dao.ArticlesRepository;
import cz.flay.fellcms.entities.Article;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/articles", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public class ArticleRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Article> getAll(){
        return articlesRepository.getAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/newest")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Article> getNewest(){
        return  articlesRepository.getNewest();
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PutMapping(path = "/save")
    public @ResponseBody HttpStatus saveArticle(@RequestBody Article article) {
        articlesRepository.save(article);
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public @ResponseBody Article getArticle(@RequestParam int id) {
        return articlesRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

I tried to log an article out to the console. Then the special charactes are displayed correctly. 
I tried a lot of things that I found in other discussions but nothing helped me.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it worked for me was to enter the following in the mysql configuration file (`my.cnf`)

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
```

The mysql configuration file is usually in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in linux (I tried it in Ubuntu 14.04). If it doesn't exist there you can create the file using `sudo touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf`; then edit the file.

**Edit:**
For Win Users: File is located in `/mysql/bin/my.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your properties file;

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&**characterEncoding=UTF-8**